# How to design an electric circuit that makes an LED light flash at 50 Hz

Tags: frequency

I have a record turntable in which the correct speed of rotation is obtained by adjusting the speed until a pattern of black/white lines on the outside edge of the platen appears stationary.

Currently a neon light flashing at mains frequency (50 Hz) shines onto the rotating pattern. It is difficult to find a replacement neon bulb and it is too dim. Hence I would like to replace it with a better system. I believe an LED light flashes at 100 Hz using 50 Hz mains.

I would be very grateful for a solution to the problem!

Thank you.
Elner

Comment: The neon is flashing at 100 Hz - 50 positive half-cycles and 50 negative of 10 ms each. You could get this using a transformer, bridge rectifier, resistor and LED but the intensity will vary with the sinewave giving you a blurry strobe. (The neon may do this too.) A better approach would be to pulse the LED maybe for 1 ms on and 9 ms off to give a sharper image.

Comment: @Transistor However, to be equivalent it would need to be sync'd to the 50 Hz mains and not left free-running or drifting over time and temperature.

Comment: Nice to hear from you again, Jonk. I am contemplating that. The mains drift may be worse than a crystal controlled solution. I used to use the turntable speed adjust to correct pitch to concert so I could jam along with them. Many albums seemed to be recorded or transferred to vinyl slightly off concert. @Elner: Let us know if you want to get into a bit of fun electronics or keep things very simple.

Comment: @Transistor I worry that any "very simple" circuit will suffer from temperature drift (days and nights, summer and winter, direct sunlight vs shadow, etc) and from time drift of parts, as well, and need calibration anyway because of part vagaries. In the US, the power grid is extremely reliable at 60 Hz over the long term and darned good even over relatively shorter times. I can't speak to the OP's situation, though. If their 50 Hz is good, the sync method would "just work" and be relatively worry free over time.

Comment: An ordinary crystal oscillator is easily stable enough for audio purposes.  A small MCU with an external reference crystal and loading caps will likely be the easiest circuit to construct; the program can simply configure a timer peripheral to generate the pulse and then the processor core suspend itself to save power.  Dedicated circuits for this kind of thing exist, but may be harder to identify and source.

Comment: @jonk: The mains frequency will average out over the day but an LP side is only about 20 minutes. See the update below. I won't even worry about it anyway!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, that was actually what I'd do in this case. But I have all the necessary tools and experience for using an MCU.

Comment: *shakes cane* in my day, we divided down from a 14.31818 MHz oscillator.  In the snow. Uphill. Both ways. *And we liked it!*

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIEYWZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple LED powered from an unsmoothed DC signal.*

Here's an almost free fix that can be tried with very little effort.

- Use a wall-wart style transformer power supply. (You may have to rummage through your junk as most are switched mode power supplies now. Go by weight!)
- If it is a DC version then strip out everything except the bridge rectifier and wire that up as shown.
- Measure the rectified DC voltage, \$ V_{DC} \$.
- Ignoring D5 for now, calculate R1 to give 20 mA through the LED. Assuming a 1.8 V drop on D1 we get \$ R1 = \frac {V_{DC} - 1.8}{20m} \$.
- With the addition of D5, a 5.1 V Zener diode the LED won't turn on until the half-wave reaches 5.1 + 1.8 V. This may narrow the pulse enough to give a sharper stroboscopic image.

[image]

*Figure 2. Here's a graph of UK 50 Hz grid from [live operating data](http://www2.nationalgrid.com/uk/Industry-information/electricity-transmission-operational-data/).*

Figure 1 shows that as I write this the UK mains frequency has dipped to 49.9 which is -0.2%. If synching the record player to this frequency everything will be a little over 3 cents (3% of a semitone) flat. Close enough for jazz?
See Pitch-to-Frequency Calculator at [Fluteopedia](http://www.flutopedia.com/pitch_to_frequency.htm).

Mains frequency is allowed to drift a little with load but will go overspeed when load reduces to pull any mains powered clocks back into synch within a day.

Comment: Wait, so the trains just run late and they're OK with that?  Clearly, not tied to the German or Swiss power grid...

Comment: @Harper The power in the UK is allowed to drift by up to ±1%, which works out as ±0.5Hz.  The frequency typically drops at times of peak load, and is compensated for by deliberately running over-frequency in the off-peak periods.

Comment: Clever to add that Zener to shrink the flash width.

Comment: And they don't use phono-turntables on the trains anyway ...